# how to recognize a real visit of web page

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework

**what we want to do :**
our system is redirecting all connections of clients to our web server (as like : www.example.com/index) .
in client PC if something (app , win update , messengers and ... ) wants to connect to the internet that will be redirect to that address .
we want to track web visits which a client visit that with opening web browser and submitting our address not those are coming from applications .

**issues :**
we are using Zend Framework , php and javascript
some applications maybe run `java scripts` , so that'll not use full (some exception).
tracking `IP address` can not possible if we want to submit visit for each page separately.
some applications get `sessions` like a visitor .  (and also cookies)

**what we do :**
using java script code for listening mouse move event and when it happen we send our log info with ajax .  so this will be show that the real visitor is visiting a page .

**Question :**
is there any better way for tracking this visits ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can try 'pinging' the server by loading a hidden image via JavaScript when the webpage loads. Something like this:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "/pingme.php";
    img.style.display = "none";

    document.body.appendChild(img);
},false);
```